# Writing XCM in lib.rs results in many errors

Tags: xcm, xcmp

I am trying to send an XCM message encoding my own pallet call to another chain.
I am struggling to write it in a universal way into lib.rs and I am receiving ton of errors.

These are the packages I import:

```rust
    use xcm::latest::prelude::*;
    use xcm_executor::*;
```

This is the code I am trying to use

```rust
     let create_collection = Self::MintCollectionReceived(origin_clone,
     collection_name, collection_description, T::ParaId::get());
     
     
                let create_collection_weight_estimation =
     Weight::from_parts(1_000_000_000, 10_000);
     
            let message = Xcm(vec![
                WithdrawAsset((Parachain(destination), 0).into()),
                BuyExecution { fees: (Parachain(destination), 0).into(), weight_limit: WeightLimit::Unlimited },
                Transact {
                    origin_kind: OriginKind::SovereignAccount,
                    require_weight_at_most: create_collection_weight_estimation, //Here program fails
                    call: create_collection.encode().into(), //Here I use my cal
                },
            ]);
```

The error I receive is on weight -  **expected `xcm::v3::Weight`, found `frame_support::weights::Weight**

I do not care about fees for now. I just want to have function, that transfers my own pallet call instruction to another node with given ID.

I've explored xTokens code and also many guides by Parity.

Many thanks for any guidance!

Another question:
If the message is fixed, how do I execute it with executor? Thanks!